# WCF settings with client credentials beyond config

Tags: wcf, authentication, active-directory, wcf-binding, networkcredentials

So I have a WCF service with netTcp binding

```
<netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="VpNetTcpBinding" portSharingEnabled="true"  closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00"
             receiveTimeout="00:22:00" sendTimeout="00:24:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="131072" >
      <reliableSession enabled="false" inactivityTimeout="00:50:00"/>
      <security mode="Transport"  >
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
```

and a WPF client that connects to said service

```
<security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
```

I've used these setting in two different DEV enviroments. In one I had to connect to the service through a VPN connection with credentials so I had to impersonate these credentials (because they tried to pass the local credentials from another domain) the service wouldn't accept.

```
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("name", "password", "domain.local");
```

This was only neccesary for me, the devoloper because others where on the same domain as the service.

Now when I setup the same way on another location I always get this error

```
System.Security.Authentication.InvalidCredentialException: The server has rejected the client credentials. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The logon attempt failed
```

I'm running the client on the same computer as the service is running, I'm remoting in but assuming the service is getting the credentials I remoted in as. I tried to impersonate those credentials the same way as before but no luck.

As the config is basically the same as in previous successful attempts I'm assuming it is some other setting here that is bothering me.

Problem is that I have no proper idea how Windows authentication works. So here are a few things I would like to suggest as possible problems without knowing or questions I would need answered to help me solve this problem.

1) When I set this security mode what am I asking precisely. As I understand I'm just asking the server if he can validate that my credentials actually exist and are trusted by the Domain. I don't have full privilege on this domain but I'm not requesting to be part of any group in the config. This is just authentication right, not authorization?

2) I'm passing in my own credentials from my own domain, I doubt this is the case as I'm running the client from within the remote and I've also tried to manually enter the credential info (impersonating).

3) Some setting in local policy. I've already set "Access this computer from the network" to authenticated users.

4) HTTP WCF activation is possibly turned off, but it shouldn't matter as this is a netTcp binding and that is turned on.

Anyone have a educated guess what could actually be the problem. Sadly WCF binding config isn't my strong suit so I could be making some very basic mistake so assume the worst.

**EDIT**

Here is some stack trace. Doesn't seem helpful

```
10/14/2013 12:26:44 
ErrorHandler
System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: The server has rejected the client credentials. ---> System.Security.Authentication.InvalidCredentialException: The server has rejected the client credentials. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The logon attempt failed
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult, Byte[] message, Exception exception)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextSend(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextSend(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.AuthenticateAsServer(NetworkCredential credential, ProtectionLevel requiredProtectionLevel, TokenImpersonationLevel requiredImpersonationLevel)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeProvider.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeAcceptor.OnAcceptUpgrade(Stream stream, SecurityMessageProperty& remoteSecurity)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeProvider.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeAcceptor.OnAcceptUpgrade(Stream stream, SecurityMessageProperty& remoteSecurity)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamSecurityUpgradeAcceptorBase.AcceptUpgrade(Stream stream)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.InitialServerConnectionReader.UpgradeConnection(IConnection connection, StreamUpgradeAcceptor upgradeAcceptor, IDefaultCommunicationTimeouts defaultTimeouts)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader.ServerFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OpenAndEnsurePump()

10/14/2013 12:26:44 
ErrorHandler-Message
The server has rejected the client credentials.

10/14/2013 12:26:44 
ErrorHandler-InnerException
System.Security.Authentication.InvalidCredentialException: The server has rejected the client credentials. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The logon attempt failed
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult, Byte[] message, Exception exception)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextSend(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextSend(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.AuthenticateAsServer(NetworkCredential credential, ProtectionLevel requiredProtectionLevel, TokenImpersonationLevel requiredImpersonationLevel)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeProvider.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeAcceptor.OnAcceptUpgrade(Stream stream, SecurityMessageProperty& remoteSecurity)
```

**Solution**

For some reason I can't explain running the client on the same computer as the WCF service was messing with it. It worked fine if ran from elsewhere.

Comment: Have you turned on WCF trace logging to see if you can glean any further information regarding the error?

Comment: @Fresh Hey I've added the Stacktrace I got from logging. I didn't create or setup the WCF service though I'm handling it now. Should I be able to increase the amount of info from the trace? I will have to read a little bit more on tracelogging in WCF.

Comment: You can log wcf info (unrelated to the stack trace, that's not what he's talking about) on both sides (client & server) changing only the configuration & then view it with a dedicated tool to read .svclog files. This will greatly help you if you enable it on both sides (you'll read the client one first, see what happens, & then check the server one & see if it errored out, at what step, or if it maybe received nothing etc).

Comment: @RonanThibaudau Yes the WCF trace was on, at least on the service side. I don't seem to find any relevant info from it. I see `receive bytes` and it trying to process the action `IConnectionRegister/Register` and 6 minutes later `CloseChannel` and `IConnectionRegister/Unregister`. I'll try to turn it on Client side as well but there is no mention of ClientCredentials here.

Comment: As @RonanThibaudau says, enabling WCF logging on the client and should give you more data to aid in your investigation. Also there is a way of linking the client and server logs so you an trace the request and responses.

Answer (score 1):

there are 3 things i normally check:

- if the IIS has the authentication mode installed. in this case, check on windows features and check if windows authentication is installed. check [iis setup](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/providers/add). Then enable this authentication mode for your service in IIS authentication window.
- NTFS permissions. IIS check if the client credentials are valid on the folder/file you access. Its the last defence off IIS.
- the credentials of the client. looks good in your case

the fact you don't have nothing on the trace is probably because its rejected by IIS before passing to your service.

Try to use WCF configuration tool, that comes width VS 2012. Avoids many mistakes.

Hope it help.